# passing arg 1 of `combine_string' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

I'm getting the compile error on the line "new_str = combine_string(newstr, "test");" Error: passing arg 1 of `combine_string' from incompatible pointer type

```
char * combine_string(char *, char *);

....

char *new_str;
new_str = newstr(item, strlen(item));
new_str = combine_string(newstr, "test");

...

char * combine_string(char *name, char *name2)
{
    char *retval;

    retval = erealloc(retval, (strlen(name) + strlen(name2) + 1));
    if (retval != NULL)
        sprintf(retval, "%s%s", name, name2);
    else
        free(name); //Wouldn't use it any longer
    return retval;
}

...


char *newstr(char *s, int l) {
    char *rv = emalloc(l + 1);

    rv[l] = '\0';
    strncpy(rv, s, l);
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: new_str and newstr are not the same thing

Comment: Ah. I had used the same name for both the variable and function name and when I changed it I forgot to add the "_" in that one spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it declared, `newstr` is a function, while `new_str` is a char*.

You probably meant to pass in `combine_string(new_str, "test");` instead of how you have it.

I might suggest giving your variables and functions more descriptive names in the future to avoid these kinds of things!

EDIT: If you're wanting to use the return value of a call to `newstr()` as arg 1 of `combine_string()` then you will have to pass the proper parameters in to `newstr()` like so

```
new_str = combine_string(newstr(other_str, length_of_other_str), "test");
```

Answer (score 1):

`newstr` is a function, apparently, not a `char *`

```
new_str = newstr(item, strlen(item));
new_str = combine_string(newstr, "test");
```

do you want:

```
new_str = combine_string(new_str, "test");
```

?